# Pyspark pandas TypeError when try to concatenate two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, concatenation

I got an below error while I am trying to concatenate two pandas dataframes:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type 'list; only ps.Series and ps.DataFrame are valid
```

At the beginning I thought It was emerged because of one the dataframe that includes list on some column. So I tried to concatenate the two dataframes that does not include list on their columns. But I got the same error. I printed the type of dataframes to be sure. Both of them are pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. Why I got this error even they are not list?

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
split_col = split_col.toPandas()
split_col2 = split_col2.toPandas()
dfNew = ps.concat([split_col,split_col2],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1455538/463168233.py in <module>
      2 split_col = split_col.toPandas()
      3 split_col2 = split_col2.toPandas()
----> 4 dfNew = ps.concat([split_col,split_col2],axis=1,ignore_index=True)

/home/anaconda3/envs/virtenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/pandas/namespace.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, sort)
   2464     for obj in objs:
   2465         if not isinstance(obj, (Series, DataFrame)):
-> 2466             raise TypeError(
   2467                 "cannot concatenate object of type "
   2468                 "'{name}"

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type 'list; only ps.Series and ps.DataFrame are valid

type(split_col)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(split_col2)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

I want to concatenate 2 dataframe but I stuck. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having this error because you're trying to concatenate two pandas DataFrames using the Pandas API for pyspark.

Instead of converting your pyspark dataframes to pandas dataframes using the *toPandas()* method, try the following:

```
split_col = split_col.to_pandas_on_spark()
split_col2 = split_col2.to_pandas_on_spark()
```

More documentation on this method.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark.html

Comment: Thanks! It works. Do you know more effective way to split columns with delimiter dynamically( I dont know which column has list and The size of list for specific column can vary ). I got the list column names and delimiter char from config file. Then I do split operation and create the dataframe whose columns are the elements of specific list column. Then combine this split column with original dataframe. I have to do these operation for all list columns and it will be very expensive.